# Error on "{\rtf1\ansi" when compiling C program

Tags: c, syntax-error

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    float fahr, celsius;
    int lower, upper, step;

    lower = 0;
    upper = 300;
    step = 20;

    fahr = lower;

    while (fahr <= upper) {
        celsius =(5.0/9.0)*(fahr-32.0);
        printf( “%3.0f %6.1f\n”,fahr,celsius );
        fahr = fahr + step;
    }
}
```

I am using a mac. In terminal, I compile with gcc -g file.c and get the following errors and warnings:

```
file.c:1:1: error: expected identifier or '('
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1265\cocoasubrtf190
^
file.c:21:11: warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
        printf( \'93%3.0f %6.1f\\n\'94,fahr,celsius );\
                 ^
```

I took the code straight out of "The C Programming Language." Why isn't it working? Also, I created the text file using text editor. However, whenever I make changes to it and save it, it reverts back to a .rtf. How do I fix that?

Comment: When you copy and paste things out of a website, sometimes the encoding for the characters is not correct.

Comment: @downvote - This is a perfectly valid question. I have missed this same thing numerous times, and the error message is hardly helpful if you don't know what you are looking for.

Comment: @Mobius, the error does indicate exactly where the bogus character is

Comment: @MattMcNabb this is fine if you know how to read this kind of error message, because of the unicode it does look kinda weird, especially if this is his first experience with `C` and he coppied it out of a book. Reading compiler errors takes time to learn.

Comment: The error message quotes a standard first line of an RTF file. That means the file is not the `.c` file you expect it to be, but rather the text editor you used is a text formatter, not a code editor, and has assigned fonts and formatting to all the embedded text.

Answer (score 11):

You saved this as an RTF file. The input file to the compiler must be plain text. If you're using the OS X TextEdit.app program, use the `Format` menu `Make Plain Text` action to convert it to plain text, then re-save it.

In addition (as mentioned by the other answers), you need to replace the special typographical quote characters (`“` and `”`) with straight double-quote characters (`"`).

Comment: Ok, I did this. Now I get these three errors:trial.c:16:10: error: non-ASCII characters are not allowed outside of literals
      and identifiers
        printf( “%3.0f %6.1f\n”,fahr,celsius );
                ^
trial.c:16:13: error: expected expression
        printf( “%3.0f %6.1f\n”,fahr,celsius );
                 ^
trial.c:16:26: error: non-ASCII characters are not allowed outside of literals
      and identifiers
        printf( “%3.0f %6.1f\n”,fahr,celsius );

Answer (score 2):

Your double-quotes are strange. Try with `printf( "%3.0f %6.1f\n",fahr,celsius );`. With this change, it compiles for me on OSX.

Comment: How do I do that kind?

Comment: Use the key on your keyboard that is to the right of the `;` key (if you have a standard keyboard layout)

Comment: @user3639182, it's the regular double-quote. On a QWERTY keyboard, it should be on the right of your keyboard, next to the return key.

Comment: Also, use a text editor that doesn't screw around with what you type in (e.g. Notepad++), instead of a RTF editor

Comment: @user3639182 The garbage in the beginning and the "funny quotes" are normally put in by a *word processor* (because it thinks it's smarter than you, and it was saved as RTF) - solution: use an appropriate *text editor*.

Comment: Don't have Notepad++. Just the TextEdit. I also used the "" in the file. Still doesn't work.

Comment: @user3639182 TextEdit is a rich text editor, which applies formatting to your text that is not understood by the compiler. In OSX, you could try something like Sublime Text - http://www.sublimetext.com/

Comment: Thanks, switching to Sublime Text worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

your quotes are richtext angled quotes. try replacing them with standard `"` quotes. this sometimes happens when coppying and pasting text from certain text editors, or the internet. The following compiles and runs for me on linux

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    main()
    {
    float fahr, celsius;
    int lower, upper, step;

    lower = 0;
    upper = 300;
    step = 20;

    fahr = lower;

    while (fahr <= upper) {
        celsius =(5.0/9.0)*(fahr-32.0);
    printf( "%3.0f %6.1f\n",fahr,celsius );
    fahr = fahr + step;
        }
    }
```