# Trying to test a discord bot; macOS terminal keeps having errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, discord.js

I've been trying to create a bot on discord and when I get to running the bot using "node bot.js" and it's having errors. Here's the full dialogue from the terminal. I installed the packages for the bot and when I try to run the bot, it says it has a bunch of issues.

```
Last login: Fri Mar 27 15:21:31 on ttys000
Jeffreys-MacBook-Pro:~ kids$ cd
Jeffreys-MacBook-Pro:~ kids$ cd Documents
Jeffreys-MacBook-Pro:Documents kids$ cd DiscordBot
Jeffreys-MacBook-Pro:DiscordBot kids$ ls
auth.json   bot.js      package.json
Jeffreys-MacBook-Pro:DiscordBot kids$ npm install discord.io winston-save
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/winston-save - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  'winston-save@latest' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/kids/.npm/_logs/2020-03-27T21_06_20_150Z-debug.log
Jeffreys-MacBook-Pro:DiscordBot kids$ npm install discord.io winston save
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN Invalid version: "ls"
npm WARN DiscordBot No description
npm WARN DiscordBot No repository field.
npm WARN DiscordBot No README data
npm WARN DiscordBot No license field.

+ discord.io@2.5.3
+ winston@3.2.1
+ save@2.4.0
added 54 packages from 44 contributors and audited 66 packages in 7.744s
found 0 vulnerabilities

Jeffreys-MacBook-Pro:DiscordBot kids$ npm install https://github.com/woor/discord.io/tarball/gateway_v6
npm WARN Invalid version: "ls"
npm WARN DiscordBot No description
npm WARN DiscordBot No repository field.
npm WARN DiscordBot No README data
npm WARN DiscordBot No license field.

+ discord.io@2.5.3
updated 1 package and audited 186 packages in 1.717s
found 0 vulnerabilities

Jeffreys-MacBook-Pro:DiscordBot kids$ node bot.js
/Users/kids/Documents/DiscordBot/bot.js:1
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1561\cocoasubrtf600
 ^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1111:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1167:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:996:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:896:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
Jeffreys-MacBook-Pro:DiscordBot kids$
```

I'm new to coding so I don't really understand what the issue is. Any suggestions on what the problem is/solutions to fix it?

Edit: here's the bot.js contents

```
const Discord = require('discord.js’);
const bot = new Discord.Client();
var server;
var DChannel;

bot.on('ready', () => {
    server = bot.guilds.get(692864223566495814);
    DChannel = server.channels.get(692864223566495817);
    console.log('--------------------\n\n\nREADY: '+ new Date() +'\n\n\n--------------------');
});

bot.on('message', (message)=>{
    if (message.channel.type.toLowerCase() == 'dm' || message.channel.type.toLowerCase() == 'group') {
        var embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setAuthor(message.author.username, message.author.avatarURL)
        .setDescription(message.content)
        .setTimestamp(new Date())
        .setColor('#C735D4');
        DChannel.send(embed);
    }
});
bot.login(process.env.TOKEN);
```

Comment: can you post the contents of your `bot.js` file in your post as well?

Comment: Yeah sorry, I just added that. It's also now saying Error: can't create duplicate variable: 'Discord'

Comment: Can you post the full error in your original post? Please include the stacktrace as well. I'm not able to reproduce your error with what you've provided so far.

Comment: Well I added the whole terminal text, not sure if that's what you were looking for... I also noticed that even when I remove the packages I installed, it has the same error messages.

Comment: Are you using TextEdit on Mac by any chance? If so, you may want to see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29175169/when-reading-files-in-python-on-mac-the-printed-out-text-is-incorrect) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23669037/error-on-rtf1-ansi-when-compiling-c-program). The syntax error seems to be from a formatting issue in TextEdit.

Comment: Ok I got the bot running now. Thanks for the help

Comment: It would help future readers if you post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there were actually a bunch of issues with the script so I did these things to fix them:
First was that I changed the text format in TextEdit to Plain Text
Second was that I put '' around the guild number and channel number in parenthesis
Third was that I changed bot.guilds.get to bot.guilds.cache.get and server.channels.get to server.channels.cache.get
Hope this helps!